# c# Automapper mapping string to 1st element of array in nested object

Tags: c#, automapper

My repository is returning back a user object which has this definition where the user will only ever have 1 email address.

User

```
    public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string  Email { get; set; }

}
```

Then I am mapping that to a UserDTO object for transmission to an environment where they expect the Email field to be an array of Email objects. So I created this Email object per what the receiving system needs and it looks like this below. We could set Type to a string with a value of "work" and Primary to boolean true;

```
    public class Email
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public bool Primary { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have my UserDTO that looks like this:

```
    public class UserReadDto
{

    public string schemas { get; set; } 

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string externalId { get; set; }

    // this should be an array of names, this is a name object. 
    public Name name { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public Email[] Emails { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to have Automapper map the email string, such as test@test.com to an Email object array that only has one Email object in it for the destination?

Comment: How would you do it without AM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that returns the list for you, something like this:

```cs
public static Email[] GetList(User x)
{
    return new List<Email>
    {
        new Email()
        {
            Value = x.Address
        }
    }.ToArray()
}
```

And then you can put this in your mapping configuration:

```cs
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<User, UserReadDto>()
       .ForMember(d => d.Emails, src =>
       {
           src.MapFrom(x => GetList(x));
       });
});
```

You can put the `GetList()` method inside your `User` model, or anywhere else really, as long as you can access it in your mapping configuration.

More info on the docs page of automapper [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html).